# Double Nesting Data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make 2 sections: one for month, one for year
Within each section: 2 pie charts inside each other, so

- month
  --> mtd pie
  --> lymtd pie
- year
  --> lyytd pie
  --> ytd pie

I have data structured like so:

```
{range:"month||year",period:"mtd||ytd||lymtd||lyytd",category_id:25,amount:100}
```

I have nested my data with

```
nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){return d.range;})
  .key(function(d){return d.period;})
  .entries(collection.toD3Json());
```

My initial data attachment is:

```
var blocks = chart.selectAll("svg")
      .data(nested, function(d){ return d.key;})
```

The key is I want to retain **object constancy** throughout, so if I attach a new nested data structure it will use existing keys or add new elements if keys don't exist.

I am having problems getting past the first data join as I want to use nested.values with another d.key but am not sure how. My best guess so far is:

```
var circles = blocks.selectAll("g.block")
         .data(function(d){ return d.key;})
    .enter().append("svg:g")
         .attr("class","block");
```

Comment: could you provide a jsFiddle to illustrate?

Comment: sorry - I solved this problem last year and don't have the answer on hand...ill try and provide the answer soon